# Cloning GitHub repository error "Fatal unable to access could not resolve host github.com"

Tags: git, git-clone, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to clone a GitHub repository in Ubuntu Server VirtualBox using the sudo command **"sudo git clone [https://github.com/username/repositoryname.git"](https://github.com/username/repositoryname.git%22)** however I got a fatal error that says **fatal:unable to access 'https://github.com/username/repositoryname.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com**. How do I solve this?

Comment: This is a local networking problem.

Comment: git config --global --unset https.proxy however it does not work for me. I still get the fatal message

Comment: Your computer cannot resolve the hostname `github.com`, so it's a DNS issue. StackOverflow isn't the right place to solve this issue.